# Разработка программ на Python

Tags: python

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, у меня есть пара вопросов...

1. Можно ли код, написанный под Python, скомпилировать в исполняемый файл?
2. Подходит ли Python для написания программ, работающих с интернетом (например, раскрутка сайта)?
3. Можно ли на Python сделать графический интерфейс?

Заранее благодарен:)

Answer (score 7):

1) Любую программу скомпилировать нельзя, только написанную специально под компилятор, например, [psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/)
2) Да, копать в сторону `cgi & web`
3) Да, например, [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro), [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/)

Comment: py2exe еще есть

Answer (score 6):

Отвечу кратко, пусть знатоки дополнят:
 1. Да, можно, гугли прогу Py2Exe (кажется так называется)
 2. Не совсем понимаю как связано написание программ с раскруткой сайта, но на питоне можно писать сайты - юзайте Django
 3. Конечно, PyQt Вам в помощь!

Comment: Py2Exe именно компилирует, а не добавляет интерпретатор к байткоду?

Comment: Вроде делает и то, и другое, хотя тут я могу неслабо гнать)

Comment: добавляет, добавляет... вшивает, можно сказать, компилятор в экзешник. как и большинство такого рода проги.

Comment: Никаких компиляторов в Py2exe и ему подобных нет, запаковывает используемые библиотеки и интерпретатор в архив, создавая псевдо-исполняемый файл. При старте этот псевдо-exe передает управление интерпретатору. Убедится в этом можно, посмотрев, сколько кушает памяти программа. Например, TortoiseHG, написанный на Python+PyQT (графическая оболочка для Mercurial), в неактивном состоянии ест 50 Мб памяти.

Answer (score 4):

1. Если у тебя питон версии 3, то py2exe тебе не поможет. Тебе нужен cx_freeze (Если все таки оно - дай знать и напишу тебе подробную инструкцию)
2. Отлично подходит
3. PyQT, как уже сказали ранее :)